# using object for ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

To avoid duplicate codes, I plan to write OOP. It's a single page app, it has many operation performed by users. For example CRUD (create, read, update & delete).

```
                var dltTask = $.ajax({
                    url: "process.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        insert: "something"
                    },
                    dataType: "text"
                });

                dltTask.done(function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                });
```

How to pass argument to ajax as object? for example in my insert,

insert = new ajax(insert, data1,data2,data3);

Comment: `data: { insert: "", data1: data1, data2: data2 }` Why don't u use like this?

Comment: because I have to write $.ajax many time. for example create, update, delete, 3 times.. duplication

Comment: Use jQuery.param( params );

Comment: Write a wrapper function then.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass values like that

```
postval = {
    data1: data1,
    data2: data2,
    data3:data3
}

var dltTask = $.ajax({
                    url: "process.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: postval,
                    dataType: "text"
                });

                dltTask.done(function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                });
```

Comment: I still need to write multiple times of the second block. this is not oop still.

Comment: overloaded if I pass unnecessary data, for example insert only need 3, I pass more than that.

Comment: unnecessary data means what and in postval you can pass more data, it will work. how u r passing php data. can u show me.

Comment: use if. for insert :

if!empty($_POST['insert'])

for update
if!empty($_POST['updt'])..

Comment: From single line we can not understand ur problem. show ur more code then we can resolve ur pbm.